# HTML Hover-Dropdown over div

Tags: html, css

So, I have a drop-down menu that goes down on hover. However whenever there is a different div underneath, the dropdown menu will be BEHIND it and therefore not fully visible.

I have fiddled with the z-index but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Add  `z-index: 9;` to this selector `#navbar`.**

**Here is the working code .**

```css
* {
 font-family: "comic sans ms";
}

.spacer {
 width: 100%;
 height:95px;
}

/* Navigation bar */

#navbar {
 width: 100%;
 height: 50px;
 background-color: deeppink;
 position: fixed;
 margin-top: 5;
 left: 0;
 color: yellow;
 
 /* non-selectable text */
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 user-select: none;
  z-index: 9;
}

.logo {
 height: 50px;
 float: left;
}

.navbutt {
 background-color: yellow;
 border: none;
 color: orange;
 height: 50px;
 width: 80px;
 font-size: 12px;
}

#comics {
 margin-left: 7px;
}

#login {
 float: right;
 margin-right: 10px;
}

#login-text {
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 3px;
}

/* Dropdown menu */

.dropdown {
 position: relative;
 display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 position: fixed;
 color: orange;
 background-color: yellow;
 margin-top: 5px;
 min-width: 80px;
 z-index: 99;
}

.dropdown-content a {
 color: orange;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding-top: 15px;
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 color: yellow;
 background-color: orange;
}

.navbutt:hover {
 color: yellow;
 background-color: mediumvioletred;
}


/* Image upload form */

.form-right {
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 margin-right: 100px;
}

/* Page Listbox */

.pagelist {
 background-color: skyblue;
 position: relative;
 float: right;
 width: 20%;
 height: 70%;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="de">
<meta charset = "UTF-8" />
<title>komix.lit - zuhause seite</title>
</head>
<body>

<div id="navbar">
<img class="logo" src="inc/logo.png" />
komix.lit
<button id="home" class="navbutt" onClick="location.href='home.php'">zuhause</button>
<button id="comics" class="navbutt" onClick="location.href='komix.php'">komix</button>
<div id=login class="navbutt dropdown"><p id='login-text'>dicctator</p><div class='dropdown-content'><span id='login-text'><a href='login.php' id='dropdown-url'>austragen</a><a href='neuerkomix.php' id='dropdown-url'>neuer Komix</a><a href='meinekomix.php' id='dropdown-url'>meine Komix</a></span></div></div></div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
<div class="content"><img src='komix\13_03_18_08_20_25-2.jpg' /><div class="pagelist"><ul><li><a href='pages.php?id=51'>Seite 1</a></li><li><a href='pages.php?id=55'>Seite 2</a></li><li><a href='pages.php?id=54'>Seite 3</a></li><li><a href='pages.php?id=52'>Seite 4</a></li><li><a href='pages.php?id=53'>Seite 5</a></li></ul></div>

</div>
</body>
<footer>
 
</footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bottom most element get higher z-index by default if we not set explicitly by CSS that's why your navbar content going behind. Change like following:

```
#navbar {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
background-color: deeppink;
position: fixed;
margin-top: 5;
left: 0;
color: yellow;
z-index: 10; // Key line

/* non-selectable text */
-moz-user-select: none;
-webkit-user-select: none;
-ms-user-select: none;
user-select: none;
}
```